# Python: group dataframe time series by nth weekdays

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, group-by, time-series

I need to run statistics in python on a dataframe over several years.
I managed to perform calculations grouping data by:

- months, days:
  sum = data.groupby([lambda x: x.month, lambda x: x.day]).sum()
- months, weekdays:
  sum = data.groupby([lambda x: x.month, lambda x: x.weekday()]).sum()

but I can not figure out how to group the data by months, nth weekdays.
By months, nth weekdays, I mean something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:
sum = data.groupby([lambda x: x.month, lambda x: x.weekday(), lambda x: ((x.day - 1) % 5) + 1]).sum()